# Powershell scripts doesn`t function well when running in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell

when I was in Powershell interface， I ran these command:

> PS C:\Users\administrator.HYPERV> Import-Module FailoverClusters
>
> PS C:\Users\administrator.HYPERV> get-module -listAvailable

I can see module FailoverClusters in result.

But when I ran Python code:

```
>>> os.system(r"powershell import-module FailoverClusters")
```

It gives me this:

> import-module：The specified module "FailoverClusters" was not loaded
>   because no valid module file was found in any module directory

and then I ran

```
>>> os.system(r"powershell get-module -listAvailable")
```

module FailoverClusters didn`t show in the result.

How can I get these python code work as I expected?

Comment: Update PowerShell to v3.0 or later and it will automatically import needed modules.

Comment: Try this PowerShell command `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess` from PowerShell directly and from Python.