# Cluster, Node from Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I have a DNS name for a cluster which has few nodes on which services are running.
I wrote powershell script first which is giving me node on which provided service is running and its state. Script uses Get-ClusterResource command
Then I wrote python script which is executing this powershell.
When I am running powershell script I am getting the node and its state. But when I am ruuning the powershell script from python I am getting error that:

```
Get-ClusterResource : The term 'Get-ClusterResource' is not recognized as the 
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.
```

I tried to use `import-module failovercluster` but did not get success.

Please let me know where I am wrong and if its not possible then I am searching for python lib to achieve the same.

Few understandings of me about cluster:
- We can not `create PSSession` for cluster.

I am running powershell script this way:

```
subprocess.check_output(["powershell.exe", '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', self.win_cluster_handling() + " -Cluster_Name " + self.cluster_name + " -ClusterNode_Action Stop-Cluster" + " -Service_Name " + self.service_name + " -Username " + self.username + " -Password " + self.password])
```

Comment: Is your PowerShell "script" that you run from Python just the single command: `powershell.exe -Command "Get-ClusterResource"` (or similar)?

Comment: yeah., it is one command, powershell.exe and then passing some parameters to it which ps1 accepts and gives the result. Insode ps1 I have command Get-CLusterResource

Comment: Ah, OK, so you are calling an actual script, not just a command. Please edit your original post and put the line of code from Python in there (rather than in the comments to the answers below).

Comment: Are you trying to query the cluster remotely with the python script? Are you testing the PowerShell script from the same machine that is running the python script?

Comment: done. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: testing powershell script from python to execute those commands to get cluster nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include `Import-module FailoverClusters` in your script also?

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846249/powershell-scripts-doesnt-function-well-when-running-in-python)

One suggestion is updating to PowerShell v3.0 or later.

Comment: Module is not included in python script. How to include it in python script. My Current powershell version is 5.1.14409.1005.  I checked this command: `os.system(r"powershell get-module -listAvailable")` from python and see that Failovercluster module is missing. How can we add it to get it listed.

Comment: When I executed command: output = 'Get-ChildItem Env: from python it not priting any variables but form powershell it does.

Comment: If you put `output =` *within* the PowerShell script, then the list of environment variables would be written to the variable and not sent to the output stream; thus powershell.exe would not return any output to the caller (python).

Comment: If you haven't done this, add the following line to your **PowerShell** script: `Import-Module FailoverClusters`. This will explicitly load the module *within* the powershell session; at the very least we'll see if this line throws an error, which would seem to prove there is a problem loading the module.

Comment: If the `Get-Module -ListAvailable` command doesn't include the **ClusterFailovers** module, then that doesn't sound too good. If you *can* see the module when running directly from PowerShell, check where it is located with: `Get-Module -ListAvailable | Sort Name | Select Name,Path`

Comment: I added import statement just before the command and I am getting error: `Import-Module : The specified module 'FailoverClusters' was not loaded because  no valid module file was found in any module directory.`

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading your description, issue occurs within the Powershell script you are invoking from Python. From within your Powershell script, can you write some lines to figure out if the script is run with the same environement varialbes, PATH etc. as when you run Powershell normally.

For example, if you run: "Get-ChildItem Env:" from Powershell, it gives you a list of environment variables. You may include the same in your powershell script and check if those are the same or if something is missing in the one run by your script.

Comment: When I run powershell alone it works. But from python it failes. When I execute this command os.system(r"powershell get-module -listAvailable") i can see that failovercluster module is missing. but when I run it from powershell then it works.

Comment: When I executed command: output = 'Get-ChildItem Env: from python it not priting any variables but form powershell it does